# How to enable swiping of a ListView when the pointer enters it in a windows store app using winrt-xaml?

Tags: winrt-xaml

When an item is selected in a ListView a different content is displayed in a WebView control located on the right of the ListView. Currently I have to click the selected item again in order to be able to swipe through the list. I want that by simply having the mouse pointer over the ListView the swiping works. I don't have a touch screen. I am using a laptop with a touch pad that understands the swipe gesture.